# Get the closest SpriteKit node in a certain direction

Tags: sprite-kit, geometry, skspritenode

I want to get the distance to the closest node (if there is a one) from another node that is "looking" at a specific direction.

In the image, the "P" is a node for the player, and the line is the direction to look at. The circe is another node, crossing the direction line.

[image]

Getting the distance between 2 nodes is not a problem, but how do I access the closest node exactly crossing my line?

Comment: Create an SKShapeNode that following the 'line of sight' and then use the 'node intersects node' method to see what nodes are on the line?

Comment: @SteveIves that would require to check every node,.  OP, look into ray tests or hit tests,  since this is what you want to be doing.  I do not know of anything offhand outside of using the physics world to get what you want done.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if you could come up with a crude example that would be a very cool snippet to see

Comment: OP, if you are just drawing a 1 pixel line in a direction.. then you could check for nodes along each point of the line with CGPath i believe. A physics solution would probably be best though.

Comment: @Fluidity I really wouldn't recommend the physics solution,  a hitTest or raycast/test is a much better way to go, especially if you know the minimum size of your sprite, because then you could skip some points on the line allowing for less searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your sprite has some radius, and `crossing my line` denotes that distance from line to sprite center is smaller than radius.

Let playur point is P, direction angle is Fi, so unit direction vector is

```
dx = cos(fi)
dy = sin(fi)
```

and line equation is

```
 - x * dy + y * dx + q = 0
 where
 q = dy * p.x - dx * p.y
```

To find distance from sprite center to this line, substitute x and y with center.x and center.y

```
dist = - center.x * dy + center.y * dx  + q
```

So walk through sprite list, check whether sprite  is intersected (`dist < spriteRadius`) and choose the closest from  intersected sprites